# Toggle class with jQuery and CSS clashing

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries, toggle

I've got a class, lets call it "responsive-table," where I have a media query to remove visibility when you reach a certain threshold on your resolution:

```
.responsive-table { display: block; }

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .responsive-table { display: none; }
}
```

When on a screen less than 600px, there is a button to toggle the visibility of this table that has a click action:

```
$(".responsive-table").toggle();
```

However once this is executed, and lets say you toggle the table on, then off, when the window is expanded to a higher resolution than 600px, .responsive-table seems to ignore the media queries of display: block; where it should become visible beyond this threshold of 600px viewport.

Comment: `toggle()` use inline style which is preponderant over style set for class

Comment: @SleekGeek OP is not wanted to toggle the class but toggle the visibility i.e. display none to block...

Comment: There isn't any - I think the .toggle() just overpowers the CSS...or maybe toggle uses a different method than display: none...I suppose I could use .css and change it in this way.

Comment: @A.Wolff, that shouldn't matter though, even if it is style inline to display none, it should use display block when the window is expanded again.

Comment: @Matt Ya it matters. You could just toggle a class instead, e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/hfwgn50o/1

Comment: @A.Wolff so..I figured out part of the problem, toggle() makes an inline edit so the tag would be <div class="responsive-table" style="display: none;"></div>

Comment: @Matt Ya, that was my first comment: `toggle() use inline style`  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascading-order

Comment: @A.Wolff Sorry, I read it as "uses display inline" hehe

Comment: @Matt My bad, my english was quite bad on it... <<toggle() use**s** inline style>>  BTW, `is preponderant` meant `takes precedence`, really my bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this with javascript

    `$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(".theTable").width() > 600) {
            $(".theTable").show();
            $(".theToggleButton").hide();
        } else {
            $(".theTable").hide();
            $(".theToggleButton").show();
            $(".theToggleButton").click(function(){
                $(".theTable").toggle();
            });
        }
    });`

Comment: Yea I was hoping to avoid this - but it looks like it may be my only option.

Comment: @Matt That's what I already updated in my answer. But I think you didn't understand?

Comment: there seems to be no way of doing this in pure css

Answer (score 0):

How about using like this?

```
.responsive-table { display: none; }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {/*notice: min-width is used*/
  .responsive-table { display: block !important; }
}
```

---

Update:

If you don't want to use !important then you can use jQuery like this (with your css code):

```
if($(window).width()<600){
   //use your code inside this
   $(".responsive-table").toggle();
}
```

Comment: I find it is bad practice to use !important in CSS...if you need to use it then something is wrong :)

Comment: why is it bad practice if this works without any further javascript?

Comment: It's not solving the problem, it's a work around that can get messy later, you add one !important and eventually you have !importants all over the place overriding each other as a project grows.

Comment: You should be when working on larger projects...and of course it's true!